# Is there an equivalent to journal impact factor for scholarly book publishers?

Tags: publications, books, publishers

I am considering writing a monograph or editing a multi-authored book. Before proceeding further, I would like to pick a suitable publisher to show them the book proposal.

To choose, I would like to see a quantitative estimate of scholarly success. I am thus wondering whether there is an equivalent to journal impact factor for scholarly book publishers?

Answer (score 1):

Thomson Reuters offers the [Book Citation Index](http://wokinfo.com/products_tools/multidisciplinary/bookcitationindex/).

**Interesting side note:** I just found this publication by [Kayvan Kousha and Mike Thelwall (2014)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/asi.23170) (posprint for free on [ResearchGade](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258211866)) stating that Google Books is a good source for Book Citations, "despite  its  lack  of  a  public  citation index."